# Change the ticks or labels on the x, y and z axis on 2d and 3d graphs to a label

Tags: plotting, ticks

I have ticks on x axis at 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 and 7. I want to change the 1 to Africa, the 2 to Asia etc. The Y axis needs to be changed from 1 to <\$10,000, 2 to \$10,000 - \$30,000 etc. I can do this in SPSS and Excel, but I do not know how to do this in Mathematica. I would like to do this for 2d and 3d graphs.

Comment: Look at `Ticks` or at `FrameTicks` in the documentation

Answer (score 1):

This could be a starting point:

```
ListPlot[data, Filling -> Axis, Ticks -> {{{1, "Africa"}, {2, "Asia"}, {3, "Europa"}, 
{4, "America\n del Norte"}, {5, "America\n del Sur"}, {{10000, 1}, {20000, 2}, 
{40000, 3}, {60000, 4}, {80000, 5}, {100000, 6}}}, 
PlotRange -> {0, 100000}]
```

[image]

I also suggest you look at `Barchart`. The `Ticks`on y-axis works in the same way. However, you should read the documentation for the `Ticks` in the x-axis

Answer (score -1):

```
Ticks -> {{{1,"Africa"},{2,"Asia}, ...},{{1,10000},{2,20000},...}}
```